# How to correctly print missing letters for each string in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am very new to coding and I have a question regarding a dict() function.

Initially, I needed to make a program that takes a string parameter and returns a new string with all the letters of the alphabet that are not in the argument string.

The requirements included using the two global parameters below and use the histogram function.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
test_miss = ["zzz","subdermatoglyphic","the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]



def histogram(s):
     d = dict()
     for c in s:
          if c not in d:
               d[c] = 1
          else:
               d[c] += 1
     return d
```

And the answer is

```
def missing_letters(s):
 h = histogram(s)
 m = []
 for c in alphabet:
 if c not in h:
  m.append(c)
 return ''.join(m)

for s in test_miss:
m = missing_letters(s)
if len(m):
 print(s,"is missing letters",m)
else:
 print(s,"uses all the letters")

**Output**
zzz is missing letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
subdermatoglyphic is missing letters fjknqvwxz
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog uses all the letters
>>>
```

And now I am trying to get rid of the histogram function  by creating a new local dictionary thinking it would work if I replace the histogram function with the new local dictionary.

```
def missing_letters(s):
    l = [1,2,3]
    h = dict(zip(s,l))
    m = []
    for c in alphabet:
         if c not in h:
           m.append(c)
    return ''.join(m)


for s in test_miss:
     m = missing_letters(test_miss)
     if len(m):
          print(s,"is missing letters",m)
     else:
          print(s,"OK")
```

However, It doesnt work.

You can see the output is different from how it is supposed to be:

```
zzz is missing letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
subdermatoglyphic is missing letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog is missing letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Why my code is not working this time?

P.S

*I want to know the way to replace a returned value of histogram (which is a dictionary) with a different local dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You are only using the first 3 letters. Instead of

```
    l = [1,2,3]
    h = dict(zip(s,l))
```

I suggest using a set:

```
    h = set(s)
```

But also, when you are calling the function you are trying to pass the whole list:

```
for s in test_miss:
     m = missing_letters(test_miss)
     # ...etc...
```

so then it is looping over list elements rather than characters in a string.

You meant:

```
for s in test_miss:
     m = missing_letters(s)
     # ...etc...
```

Comment: I also take your advice into consideration and it worked! Thank you so much

Comment: oh, I almost forgot about the reason I asked the question.  What is the way to make it work using a dictionary function? the  reason I am asking about this is that when I use the returned value of histogram function which is a dictionary, it works. So I want to know the reason why my dictionary cannot be replaced with the returned value of histogram function to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

By using two lists inside a function you should be able to emulate that. This code does the trick:

```
def lettercheck(sentence):
    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    letters = list(letters)
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    sentence = list(sentence)
    missing_letters = []
    for letter in letters:
        if letter not in sentence:
            missing_letters.append(letter)
    return ''.join(missing_letters)
```

After it all you have to do is call the function and passing it a parameter.

**EDIT:** As an explanation to the comment, you actually can use the missing_test in order to pass multiple sentences and run the function from them. The simplest way to do that would be this:

```
for i in missing_test:
    i = lettercheck(i)
    print(i)
```

As for why I use the lists, I'll try to briefly explain step by step what the code does.

1- `def lettercheck(sentence):` stores whatever string parameter you pass it into a variable.

2- `letters` is equal to what you stated as `alphabet`, which is then turned into a list on the line `letters = list(letters)`. If you print letters after that point, the output would be `[a,b,c,(...)]`.

3- The string you pass is lowered (so you can check for capitals too) and then turned into a list, so zzz turns into [z,z,z].

4- An empty list (missing_letters) is created since later on it will be the output.

5- The for loop here checks every letter in the alphabet and then checks if it's on the list created for the parameter you pass. If it's inside the list, it does nothing. If it's not, then it adds that letter to the missing_letters list.

6- `return ''.join(missing_letters)` gives back the list of missing letters as a string.

Comment: Wow It worked! Thank you so much, what is the reason I cannot directly use the test_miss inside the function ?  and why do you use the list function there?

Comment: What I want to do is still to use a dictionary function. The returned value of histogram is a dictionary and what is a way to replace it with a local dictionary?

Comment: In general you want to have just one function do the whole job, so the part of adding the output to a dictionary can be done inside the lettercheck function so it returns a dictionary, although I'm not following you in terms of which would be the key and its respective value in this case.

Comment: As in the histogram function, keys are the strings from test_miss, so that is why I am trying to make a dictionary inside a function using strings as keys and adding numbers as values imitating histogram function... Could you show me a way to do that using a dictionary?